# Cracks in texture

Tags: texturing

I'm importing an .obj from Agisoft photoscan into Blender. For some reason you can see lines in the texture - it appears to be the joints in the texture map and is still visible after rendering.

Can anyone tell me how to remove these joints?

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the UV editor with the Texture? or a .blend file with a portion of the object + texture?. Could be the lack of "pixel bleeding" in the uv's edges, so the filtering blends whatever color is outside the UVs, but could be something else.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue or perhaps a similar one. With my UV Map I had to add more bleed to the texture as a crisp bleed left a trail of missed stuff in some other programs I imported too.

It appear you're having the same issue. Try increasing bleed and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

check for duplicate vertices : enter the edit mode, select all the mesh and click remove duplicate vertices in the left toolbar.
Still in edit mode on the property bar go material, select each material and see the UV image editor is the unfolding of the mesh is correct : Select the material and the corresponding image in the UV image editor. the banks of the consequences should match the edges of the image .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my 3d scan. How I fixed it was by unchecking "Use Alpha" in the texture options panel.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue because I was exporting the texture as a png--exporting as a jpg fixed the problem. This may be an option for you.